# MySQL PHP - UTF8 data is inserted codified

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, utf-8

I have a table in a mysql database with the charset set to **utf8** and collate **utf8_general_ci**, in my php project I am performing insertions, however, data containing accent are inserted "encoded"
Ex: 
word **Inteligência** when sended to database is converted to **Inteligu00eancia**

[Table with encoded data (Look for field Lastname)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B77bB.png)

Comment: Did you read this **[very informative q/a about UTF8, right here on SO!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)** and review your solution.  A must read, really.

Comment: Yeah, i read question, but not solve my problem, the problem persists...

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - nice try, but it does not cover Unicode encodings. with `\u...`.

Comment: @RickJames true true true.  So true in fact, i forbid straight use of json_encode from some of my stack in favour of my own 'unicode' friendly version.  Done that so long ago i f'got about it !

Answer (score 2):

No, "Utf8 all the way" does not address this case.

You have `\u00ea`, the Unicode representation.  You want hex `C3AA`.

One place that generates the Unicode is PHP's json_encode; add an extra parameter:

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

(The backslash vanished due to it being an escape character.)